# Small resolution of a variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $Y$ is a hypersurface in $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}}^4$ defined by 
\begin{equation}
X\,W-Y\,Z=0
\end{equation}
where $X,Y,Z$ and $W$ are the coordinates of $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}}^4$. The singular locus of $Y$ is just a double point at origin and it admits a small resolution in a simple way: take a product $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}}^4 \times \mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{Q}}$, then the variety $\hat{Y}$ is the variety defined by
\begin{equation}
X \,t_0+Y\,t_1=0 \\
Z \,t_0+W \,t_1=0
\end{equation} 
The natural projection $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}}^4 \times \mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{Q}}\rightarrow \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}}^4$ defines a birational morphism
\begin{equation}
\pi: \hat{Y} \rightarrow Y
\end{equation}
The exceptional curve is just $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{Q}}$. If now $Z$ is the hypersurface in $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}}^4 $ defined by
\begin{equation}
X^2+Y^2+Z^2+W^2=0
\end{equation}
What is the small resolution $\hat{Z}$ of $Z$? Is the exceptional curve now $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{Q}}$ or a conic (with no rational point)

If extend the field to $\mathbb{Q}(i)$, the hypersurfaces $Y$ and $Z$ are isomorphic, I guess this isomorphism extends to an isomorphism between $\hat{Y}$ and $\hat{Z}$ (over $\mathbb{Q}(i)$), what happens on the exceptional curve under this isomorphism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the exceptional curve of $\hat{Z}$ is a conic with no rational points. This can be seen as follows. The blowup of the exceptional curve on a small resolution is isomorphic to the blowup $\tilde{Z}$ of $Z$ at the origin. Thus, to understand $\hat{Z}$ one needs to find a contraction of $\tilde{Z}$. Note that the exceptional divisor of $\tilde{Z}$ is isomorphic to the quadric $Q$
$$
x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + x_4^2 = 0
$$
in $\mathbb{P}^3$. The contraction of $\tilde{Z}$ contracts $Q$ onto the exceptional curve of $\hat{Z}$, its fibers form a family of lines on $Q$. Thus the exceptional curve of $\hat{Z}$ is the connected component of the Hilbert scheme of lines on $Q$. It remains to note that this Hilbert scheme indeed has two components defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, one of them is defined by the equations
$$
x_{12} + x_{34} = x_{13} - x_{24} = x_{14} + x_{23} = x_{12}^2 + x_{13}^2 + x_{14}^2 = 0,
$$
and the other by the equations
$$
x_{12} - x_{34} = x_{13} + x_{24} = x_{14} - x_{23} = x_{12}^2 + x_{13}^2 + x_{14}^2 = 0
$$
inside the Plucker space $\mathbb{P}^5$. Both conics have no rational points.

Comment: Thank you. I guess small resolution is not canonical, which is different from blowing up. So is it a general principal that if you want to understand small resolution, you can look at the contraction of the blowing up instead?

Comment: I cannot say it is a general principal, but this definitely works for ordinary double points in dimension 3.

Comment: I see. I guess this also proves the existence of small resolution of ordinary double points in dimension 3!

Comment: Not quite. The first problem is that components of the Hilbert scheme of conics may be undefined over $\mathbb{Q}$ (i.e., swapped by the Galois group). In this case small resolutions are not defined over $\mathbb{Q}$. The second problem, is that a small resolution is not necessarily projective (so it is only defined as an algebraic space).

Comment: Sorry for asking you again after nearly three months about this question. I am trying to construct the small resolution of the double point of a threefold, if such a small resolution exists, it is not projective. From your comment, it is only defined as an algebraic space if it exists. Do you know any references about this? i.e. construct non-projective small resolution using algebraic spaces. Thank you very much.